# i've got some issues with the installed Python 3.8.5 , whenever i try to import a package it shows an error which says : No module named '.....'

Tags: package-management, python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

To install [`matplotlib`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/matplotlib) for system python use commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```